# Find shared elements in a list

Tags: r

I can find the shared elements from each data in a small list. A simplified example is here:

```
data_1 <- c("A","B")
data_2 <- c("A","B","C")
data_3 <- c("A","B","C","D")
data_4 <- c("A","B","F","N")

list.a <- list(data_1,data_2,data_3,data_4)

# find common elements
shared <- Reduce(intersect, list(list.a[[1]], list.a[[2]], list.a[[3]]), list.a[[4]]))  

# outputs
print(shared)                 
[1] "A" "B"
```

But the problem in real work is: The list is really large, say it contains 100 data, then this approach is not efficient anymore, and may introduce mistakes. Is there a way to avoid listing all of them`list(list.a[[1]], list.a[[2]], list.a[[3]]), list.a[[4]])`? Something short and neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use your list rather than listing its sub-elements.

```
(shared <- Reduce(intersect, list.a))
# [1] "A" "B"
```

Comment: WOW. Thanks! I learned that approach from another post on stackoverflow, I never knew it can work like this!

Answer (score 0):

Here, is another option with `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
list.a %>%
      reduce(intersect)
```